# Pie graph based on cell color

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to make a pie graph that shows the same colors as the cells and with the cell text as the label.

It is showing up as a bar graph.

[image]

My Excel file https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1GLuBx-ROnhVUFoQTlMU2RqWGs/edit?usp=sharing

```
Sub ColorBreakdown()

Dim rCell As Range
Dim lRedCount As Long, lGreenCount As Long, lYellowCount As Long

    For Each rCell In Range("A1:A" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
        Select Case rCell.Interior.Color
            Case RGB(230, 184, 183)
                lRedCount = lRedCount + 1
            Case RGB(216, 228, 188)
                lGreenCount = lGreenCount + 1
            Case RGB(255, 255, 153)
                lYellowCount = lYellowCount + 1
        End Select
    Next rCell

    With ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=100, Width:=375, Top:=75, Height:=225)
    With .Chart
        .SeriesCollection.NewSeries.Values = Array(lRedCount, _
            lGreenCount, lYellowCount)
        With .SeriesCollection(1)
            .Points(1).Interior.Color = RGB(230, 184, 183)
            .Points(3).Interior.Color = RGB(216, 228, 188)
            .Points(5).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 153)
        End With
        .ChartType = xlPie
        .HasLegend = False
    End With
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Which line produces the error. Is it highlighted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. I used the standard R,G,B colors for ease in testing.

**Tried and Tested:**

```
Dim rCell As Range
Dim lRedCount As Long, lGreenCount As Long, lBlueCount As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim SChrt As Shape
Set ws = ActiveSheet

    For Each rCell In Range("A1:A" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
        Select Case rCell.Interior.Color
            Case RGB(255, 0, 0)
                lRedCount = lRedCount + 1
            Case RGB(0, 255, 0)
                lGreenCount = lGreenCount + 1
            Case RGB(0, 0, 255)
                lBlueCount = lBlueCount + 1
        End Select
    Next rCell

    'Debug.Print lRedCount, lGreenCount, lBlueCount

    Set SChrt = ws.Shapes.AddChart(xlPie, 100, 375, 75, 225)
    With SChrt.Chart
         .SeriesCollection.NewSeries.Values = Array(lRedCount, _
            lGreenCount, lBlueCount)
        With .SeriesCollection(1)
            .Points(1).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
            .Points(2).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)
            .Points(3).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 255)
        End With
    End With
```

I made minor revisions on your code.
One is adding `ws` variable declared as `WorkSheet` and `SChrt` as `Shape`.
The reason is for the `Intellisense` to kick in. Somehow, it is not showing using `ActiveSheet`.
Second is using `Shape` instead of `ChartObjects`.
Basically we added a `Chart` under the `Shape` collection.
With the `Intellisense` fired, it is easy to set the arguments.
The rest is the same from your code with some minor difference in colors.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Awesome it works! How do I add my own names to the colors, the percentage and a title to the top such as [this](http://i.imgur.com/KpQReyQ.png)? I did some googling and tried adding .Name(1) = "Value1" etc but that just returned an error